# HTML/CSS - Text not aligning/justifying in centre

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to overlay an image with some text. I can not seem to get it to justify/align in the centre of the overlay. I've tried both with the class and the id and it still won't justify/align.

See the image below as well if that helps. I can create a border through the text id but for reasons I do not know the text will not justify/align in the centre.

Thanks in advance

## Code snippet

```css
body {
    display:grid;
    grid-template-columns:1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
    grid-gap:5px;
    grid-template-areas: "header header" "imageOrder imageInvoice";
    background:#eee;
  }

  header{
      grid-area: header;
      place-self: center;
  }

  #imageInvoice{
      grid-area: imageInvoice;
      background-color: chartreuse;
      place-self: center;
  }

.image {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    place-self: center;
  }

#imageOrder{ /*a.k.a container*/
    grid-area: imageOrder;
    background-color: springgreen;   
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    max-width: 500px; 
}
  
  #overlayOrder{
    position: absolute;
    right: -20px;
    bottom: -20px;     
    background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); /* Black see-through */
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    transition: .5s ease;
    opacity:0;
    padding: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    text-justify: center;
  }
  #imageOrder :hover#overlayOrder {
    opacity: 1;
  }

  .Text {
    text-align: center;
    text-justify: center;
    place-self: center;
    color: lawngreen;
  }

  #orderText {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      
      align-self: center;
      vertical-align: center;
      place-self: center;
      text-align: center;
      text-justify: center;
      border: 4px solid red;
      justify-self: center;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="homeCSS.css">
</head>

<title>
    Home Page
</title>

<body>
    <header class="header">
        <h1>Welcome [User Name]</h1>
    </header>
        <div class="image" id="imageOrder">
            <a href="entry.html">
            <img src="images/theLogo.png" class="imageLinks" id="orderForm">
            <div class="overlay" id="overlayOrder">
                <div class="Text" id="orderText">
                    Overlay Text
                </div>               
            </div>     
            </a>       
        </div>
        
        <div class="image" id="imageInvoice">
            <a href="invoice.html" >
            <img src="images/theLogo.png" class="imageLinks" id="invoiceForm">
            <div class="overlay" id="overlayInvoice">
                <div class="Text" id="invoiceText">
                    Inovice Overlay
                </div>               
            </div>    
            </a>        
        </div>



</body>


</html>
```

[image: Overlay Image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the display flex attribute to center all elements in a container like this. But I am not sure if this answer your question.

```css
body {
    display:grid;
    grid-template-columns:1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
    grid-gap:5px;
    grid-template-areas: "header header" "imageOrder imageInvoice";
    background:#eee;
  }

  header{
      grid-area: header;
      place-self: center;
  }

  #imageInvoice{
      grid-area: imageInvoice;
      background-color: chartreuse;
      place-self: center;
  }

.image {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    place-self: center;
  }

 .image > a {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

#imageOrder{ /*a.k.a container*/
    grid-area: imageOrder;
    background-color: springgreen;   
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    max-width: 500px; 
}
  
  #overlayOrder{
    position: absolute;
    right: -20px;
    bottom: -20px;     
    background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); /* Black see-through */
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    transition: .5s ease;
    opacity:0;
    padding: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    text-justify: center;
  }
  #imageOrder :hover#overlayOrder {
    opacity: 1;
  }

  .Text {
    text-align: center;
    text-justify: center;
    place-self: center;
    color: lawngreen;
  }

  #orderText {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      
      align-self: center;
      vertical-align: center;
      place-self: center;
      text-align: center;
      text-justify: center;
      border: 4px solid red;
      justify-self: center;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="homeCSS.css">
</head>

<title>
    Home Page
</title>

<body>
    <header class="header">
        <h1>Welcome [User Name]</h1>
    </header>
        <div class="image" id="imageOrder">
            <a href="entry.html">
            <img src="images/theLogo.png" class="imageLinks" id="orderForm">
            <div class="overlay" id="overlayOrder">
                <div class="Text" id="orderText">
                    Overlay Text
                </div>               
            </div>     
            </a>       
        </div>
        
        <div class="image" id="imageInvoice">
            <a href="invoice.html" >
            <img src="images/theLogo.png" class="imageLinks" id="invoiceForm">
            <div class="overlay" id="overlayInvoice">
                <div class="Text" id="invoiceText">
                    Inovice Overlay
                </div>               
            </div>    
            </a>        
        </div>



</body>


</html>
```